A blazor component won't be disposed because of a static variable HotReloadManager.Default
I'm using Blazor server web app (.net 8), I did i magration from blazor wasm to blazor web app, nw i'm trying to optimize the memory usage and while investigating of Visual Studio performance profiler i noticed that i have ultiple instances of the same page (number of inctances = the number of times i navigated to the page), and i got this reference in the hot path view.
enter image description here
I tried diactivating the hotreload in visual studio other than that i don't have any idea...

Developer-built components that implement IComponent can take low-level control over rendering at the cost of having to manually trigger rendering with events and lifecycle methods that the developer must create and maintain.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
